# Meaning of 親子同士のペア in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, words, manga, sports

Context: In the manga リクドウ, Riku is going to fight against Hyodo. **Hyodo** is a boxer and the son of a former world champion boxer, so he's a thoroughbred (サラブレッド). He didn't have a good relationship with his father so he moved to Yoneda Boxing Gym. **Yoneda** is a trainer that has recently inherited his father's boxing gym. The two seem to make a good team together. Hearing about all this, Riku's trainer says:

> ボクシング**親子同士のペア**か…強敵だな

What is the meaning of ボクシング親子同士のペア? To me it translates to "a boxing couple with a father-and-son-like relationship", but the fact that they seem to be about the same age made me think that my translation could be wrong. Could it refer to the fact that they both continued the profession of their fathers and so, in a certain sense, they are both thoroughbred?

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/nuV8tDM.jpg) you can see the original page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ボクシング親子 in this context means "Both father and his son participate in boxing". Hyodo's and Yoneda's father are familiar with boxing, so they are ボクシング親子 each other.

Answer (score 2):

X親子 normally refers to a parent and a child where both of the two are X (or related to X) (e.g., 料理人親子, 天才親子). Y同士のペア refers to a pair where the two members are both Y (e.g., 大学生同士のペア, 男同士のペア).

Actually, ボクシング親子同士のペア is a puzzling expression to me; an 親子 is already a kind of pair, so it sounds like "pair of pairs". It could mean "a pair consisting of a parent and his/her child", although redundant. However, judging from the picture, this ペア seems to be referring to the two sons drawn in the previous frame. Logically speaking, it should've been ボクシング親子の息子の方同士のペア or ボクシング関係の親を持つ子同士のペア. Maybe the author shortened the expression knowing the readers would understand the intended meaning with the aid of the picture...